# Swiper issue after deploying to gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, swiper.js

I'm making portfolio sections in my project. The portfolio is fetched from gh using the tanstack query library. I use swiper to display tiles of individual projects. My problem is that when I run the app on localhost, everything works fine and the tiles are displayed in the swiper. However, after deploying the page to gh-pages, the projects are displayed one after the other without any swiper (although in devtools you can see the dependencies for the swiper) what can be the reason for this.

` 
{inView && (
<>

```
                <CustomSwiper<React.ComponentType<any>>

                    breakpoints={{
                        900: {
                            slidesPerView: 3,
                            spaceBetween: 40,

                        },
                    }}

                    effect={'coverflow'}
                    centeredSlides={true}
                    slidesPerView={1}
                    modules={[Navigation, Scrollbar, EffectCoverflow, Pagination]}
                    spaceBetween={40}
                    grabCursor={true}
                    pagination={{
                        clickable: true,
                    }}
                    navigation
                    coverflowEffect={{
                        rotate: 50,
                        stretch: 0,
                        depth: 100,
                        modifier: 1,
                        slideShadows: true,
                    }}
                >

                    {data && data.map((repo) => (
                        <CustomSlide key={repo.id}>
                            <Container>
                                <ProjectTitle>{repo.name}</ProjectTitle>
                                <Description>{repo.description}</Description>
                                <LinksWrapper>
                                    <Caption>Repository:</Caption>
                                    <Projectlink href={repo.html_url} target='_blank'>{repo.html_url}
                                      </Projectlink>
                                </LinksWrapper>
                                <LinksWrapper>
                                    <Caption>Website:</Caption>
                                    <Projectlink href={repo.homepage} target='_blank'>{repo.homepage}
                                 </Projectlink>

                                </LinksWrapper>
                            </Container>
                        </CustomSlide>
                    ))}
                </CustomSwiper>
                <TitleWrapper>
                    <Title rightvariant smaller>Portfolio</Title>
                </TitleWrapper>
            </>)}
    </Wrapper >`
```

I don't know what could be wrong because as I wrote on localhost everything works